# Why webpack removes slash from url passed as parameter to loader

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I need to replace string in my css with some url depends on environment variables. I'm trying to use [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader). So I have this in my webpack config:

```
loaders: [
  // ...
  {test: /\.css$/, loader: `style!css!string-replace?search={{ASSETS_URL}}&replace=${ASSETS_URL}&flags=g`}
]
```

`ASSETS_URL` is i.e. http://foo.bar/biz.

This works but `{{ASSETS_URL}}` is replaced by http:/foo.bar/biz (missing slash after http).

I've logged input of string-replace-loader and it receives `?search={{ASSETS_URL}}&replace=http:/localhost:8080/assets&flags=g` as `this.query`.

I tried to escape slashes but it doesn't help.

Why is this happening? Any chance to disable such behavior?

**UPD:** node version: 6.4.0, webpack version: 1.13.2, webpack-dev-server version: 1.16.2.

Comment: @Kreozot updated OP with versions. I'll try to update everything webpack related and let you know.